# Why does OAuth provide both an access token and an access token secret? Why not just a single value?

Tags: oauth

Why does OAuth include both an access token and an access token secret as two separate values? As a consumer or OAuth, all of the recommendations that I have seen indicate that I should store the token and secret together and essentially treat them as one value.

So why does the specification require two values in the first place?

Comment: I may have answered my own question, but I suspect the reason is indexing for the OAuth provider. A provider can efficiently lookup a record by access token and then verify the access token secret, rather than having to lookup a long and not-very-indexable combination.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually, the access token secret is never transmitted to the provider. Instead, requests transmit the access token, and then use the secret to sign the request. That is why you need both: one to identify, and one to secure

Comment: But then why does Twitter have us transmit the secret now too?  See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Not quite sure why. That's probably something you'd wanna direct at Twitter themselves. But either way, one important thing to note is that their method **requires** SSL in order to be secure.

Comment: Good point about SSL, but then I'm back to not understanding why we need a key AND a secret.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 secrets, one is token secret and other is consumer secret. Secrets are used to sign the requests (to generate the oauth signature) but not transmitted in the request header where token is sent in the header to identify the client and verify if it has access.