# Should the OAuth 1.0 request secret be hidden from the user?

Tags: security, oauth, pki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does OAuth provide both an access token and an access token secret? Why not just a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740559/why-does-oauth-provide-both-an-access-token-and-an-access-token-secret-why-not)

I am confused as to why the OAuth 1.0 request token is split into a key and secret. I can't figure out what attack vectors are made possible by the Consumer revealing the secret to the User along with the key. A man-in-the-middle still won't have the consumer secret, and thus will be unable to forge any requests on behalf of the Consumer. Further, any man-in-the-middle with the ability to see the request token's secret would, in theory, also have the ability to forge the User's anyway, such that even if the Consumer hides the secret from the User, the MITM will be able to impersonate the User and cause the same damage.

It seems like I'm missing something here... There must be some kind of advantage to hiding the secret from the User, otherwise why even have a "secret" in the first place? Does it have to do with keeping the OAuth request signature more difficult to forge?

Comment: okay, maybe not a duplicate. You are asking about the request token, not the access token, right? Sorry...

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the request token, although it's possible that the same logic holds. I'm not sure, though... And even then, the logic that I'm reading there just doesn't make much sense to me. I still have trouble dealing with the idea that any MITM capable of grabbing a token secret would be able to session hijack anyway, so why even bother?

Comment: I think the whole thing hinges on keeping an attacker from getting to the secret (that's why it's called "secret"). For example, it is not transmitted over the network (after the initial exchange), whereas the key is.