# Can Outh2.0 access_tokens be compromised?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, access-token, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am learning more on Oauth2 concepts and is very much interested in using Spring Oauth2 module. I am a bit lost when learning about access tokens. How can we prevent the access_tokens from being compromised? I understand that the whole token exchange happens using HTTPS, however when a client  can access to a resource using HTTP.  Also, the access_token could be short lived, but it does have a window where it can be compromised.  Is my understanding correct?

How can this be prevented? I see some mention of token_secret that could be passed along with the access_token, but I am not sure if Spring’s OAuth 2 implementation uses it.

[What is the Access Token vs. Access Token Secret and Consumer Key vs. Consumer Secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057430/what-is-the-access-token-vs-access-token-secret-and-consumer-key-vs-consumer-s)

Please correct me if I am on a wrong track. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. An access token can be compromised through several threats (see [RFC6819](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819) for some threat models).

But some specifications (or ongoing specification) add ways to prevent access tokens from being compromised or to help you to limit bad effects if stolen.

- Revoke access tokens: [RFC7009](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7009)
- Bind tokens to the SSL connection: [OAuth 2.0 Token Binding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-token-binding)
- [A Method for Signing HTTP Requests for OAuth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-signed-http-request)
- [PoP access token type](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-pop-architecture) and [RFC7800](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7800)