# Are Both Access Tokens + Access Token Secret Really Necessary?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5

I'm building an API which allows our customers to interact with my PHP application programmatically. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2740559/15153975) it seems that I should provide the users of my application with two keys:

**1)** `access token secret` (a *very* long string of random characters)

**2)** `access token` (a much shorter string of random characters or numbers)

The idea behind these two tokens is so that the client signs (encrypts) his request with the `access token secret` and transmits the request to our server. However, since the request is encrypted there's no way for the server to decrypt the message without first identifying which client is sending the request. The purpose of the "access token" is to help the server easily identify (look up) which client's "access token secret" to use to decrypt the message. Obviously, the client should not send the actual access token secret with the request as this would allow an adversary to intercept the client's secret token and sign messages on his behalf without his knowledge. Is this correct?

Assuming my understanding is correct, why not have the client simply use his username (the one he usually uses to login to his online account) instead of generating a custom access token?

Comment: So the point is that the access token is identifiable by the server but not human readable identifiable so to be able to identify someone through their access token they would need both the access token and the backend database that links the two records. It's a very common security practice that you never rely solely on one method of security. but you can also use them specific to an application so if another application tries to hijack an access token it's not going to work.

Comment: @Barkermn01 Ah, so basically we don't want a potential adversary to even be capable  of identifying the sender of the request, even though he has no way to decrypt the message? Presumably, this would be a security risk because say if he was able to identify the customer who sent the request he might be able to deduce other info about the sender (For example, that the request is being sent by a customer with large funds and so on)? Once he knows this info, he could use it to determine if it makes sense to continue attacking this client..

Comment: yeah, it can also be used to limit the access token to specific applications say by Origin header if via javascript or IP if from server-side tech, so an example would be a request that sends a client_id key with the request, the access token is limited to that client_id only and that client is only allowed to be used from a specific origin you can help secure the access.

Answer (score 0):

Each account may have many access tokens at any given time, each with their own secret.  There are several benefits to this, including:

- Scoping specific tokens for specific purposes, to limit access.  (Maybe one system needs access to read/write everything, but perhaps some other system only needs read access to one part of an API.)
- Monitoring.  (It's a lot easier to see what's using what, and when, when they all use different tokens.)
- Replacing tokens.  You don't want downtime while you deploy a new key, so you can have multiple active at the same time, and then disable the old key later.

There may also be other reasons specific to the system you're using.  For example, in my case, the key ID plays a part in verifying the secret.